# Why does string.Split(" ") returns elements even when the separator is not present?

Tags: c#, .net

In the following:

```
string input = "123";
char [] separators = " ".ToCharArray();
string [] elements = input.Split(separators);
```

the `elements` array is of .Length = 1.

Why is that? String `123` does not contain any spaces.

Comment: If you try to split a string, but the split position is not existent, what do you get? The un-split string. In other words, if you can't split the string, the string remains the string...

Comment: @elgonzo So there is no situation where .Length will be 0 and elements array will be empty?

Comment: If a string consists only of split-separators, and you instruct the Split method to discard empty entries, then empty array. See here for a demonstration: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hWG2Hc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___):

> If this instance does not contain any of the characters in separator, the returned array consists of a single element that contains this instance.

For your second question:

> So there is no situation where .Length will be 0 and elements array will be empty?

Yes there is - if you use the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option on a string that is empty or contains nothing but delimiters:

```
string input = "---";
char [] separators = new [] {'-'};
string [] elements = input.Split(separators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```